# Bqplot rendering new bar at each step in animation instead of moving the original bar

Tags: python, bqplot

I am trying to animate a bar chart in Bqplot.  I would like to be able to update both the x and y values for the bars and have them adjust smoothly. 
The code below behaves as expected for 2 of the 3 bars in my chart, but the 3rd bar is redrawn completely at each timestep.

I was initially trying this with only 2 bars.  The first bar behaved as expected, but the 2nd would be redrawn at each timestep.  I added the 3rd bar to try solve the problem.

```
initialIndex = 0
idxSlider3 = IntSlider(min=0, max=20, step=1, 
    description='Index',value=initialIndex)

''' I want to update the bar chart with this function '''
def update_chart3(change):
    with bar3.hold_sync():
        bar3.x = [idxSlider3.value, 
             idxSlider3.value + 1, 
             idxSlider3.value + 2]
        bar3.y = [idxSlider3.value, idxSlider3.value, idxSlider3.value] 

idxSlider3.observe(update_chart3, 'value')  

fig3 = plt.figure(animation_duration=1000)

bar3 = plt.bar(x=[0, 1, 2], y=[1, 1, 0])

play_button3 = Play(min=0, max=20, step=1, interval=1000, initial_value=0)
jslink((play_button3, 'value'), (idxSlider3, 'value'))

VBox([HBox([idxSlider3, play_button3]), fig3])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way of making the 'bars' animate nicely in x.  It can't be done with bars.  Instead I've used line marks -   which is a hack.  But you get the flexibility.   And I prefer using Bqplot in the object model (rather than the pyplot way).

[image]

```py
import bqplot as bq
from ipywidgets import *
import numpy as np

initialIndex = 0
xBar=[0, 2, 4] 
yBar=[1, 1, 0]
zeroY = 0
barWidth = 1

idxSlider3 = IntSlider(min=0, max=20, step=1, 
    description='Index',value=initialIndex)

''' I want to update the bar chart with this function '''
def update_chart3(change):
    xBar = [idxSlider3.value, 
         idxSlider3.value + 2, 
         idxSlider3.value + 4]
    np.random.rand()
    yBar = [idxSlider3.value + np.random.rand()*2, idxSlider3.value + np.random.rand()*2, idxSlider3.value + np.random.rand()*2] 
    xList, yList = getLineCoordsFromBarLike(xBar, yBar)
    lines.x = xList
    lines.y = yList

idxSlider3.observe(update_chart3, 'value')  

x_sc = bq.LinearScale()
y_sc = bq.LinearScale()

x_ax1 = bq.Axis(label='', scale=x_sc, num_ticks = 3)
y_ax1 = bq.Axis(label='', scale=y_sc, orientation='vertical')

def getLineCoordsFromBarLike(xBar, yBar):
    """ Convert of single list of bar coordinates to a 2D array of line coordinates that describe the rectangular shape

    xBar: 1D list of numbers for central x position of bar chart
    yBar: 1D list of numbers for amplitudes of bar chart  (must be same length as xBar)

    retrns x cordinates 2D array, y coordinates 2D array.   
    """
    xList= []
    yList= []
    for num, x in enumerate(xBar):
        y = yBar[num] 
        xList.append([x - barWidth/2, x - barWidth/2, x + barWidth/2, x + barWidth/2,])
        yList.append([zeroY, y, y, zeroY])
    x_ax1.tick_values = xBar 
    return xList, yList

xList, yList = getLineCoordsFromBarLike(xBar, yBar)   

lines = bq.Lines(x=xList, y=yList,
    scales={'x': x_sc, 'y': y_sc},
    colors=['black'], 
    display_legend=True, 
#     tooltip=def_tt,
    stroke_width = .5,
     close_path = True,
     fill = 'inside',
    fill_colors = bq.colorschemes.CATEGORY10 * 10
    )

margins = dict(top=10, bottom=40, left=50, right=30)
fig3 = bq.Figure(marks=[lines], axes=[x_ax1, y_ax1], fig_margin=margins, animation_duration=1000)
fig3.layout.width = '600px'
fig3.layout.height = '600px'

# def_tt = bq.Tooltip(fields=['name',], formats=['',],  labels=['id', ])
play_button3 = Play(min=1, max=20, step=1, interval=1000, initial_value=0)
jslink((play_button3, 'value'), (idxSlider3, 'value'))

VBox([HBox([idxSlider3, play_button3]), fig3])
```

Comment: That's great, answers my question completely.
However, what I was ultimately hoping to do was to have a 'stacked' bar chart.  Then be able to move the top component of a bar, from one bar to another.  
I don't think this method will allow me to move bars relative to each other on the x axis?

Comment: You can do a stacked bar chart and move each bar around. You just have to change the code to adjust the coordinates of the vertices. With moderate Python skills, it is possible to be really creative in BQplot, without needing to write Javascript.    Thats why i'm a big fan of BQplot and ipywidgets.

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'adjust' smoothly, you want the bars to shift to the right, without redrawing? I don't think bqplot 'moves' bars like that. The data for the new bars 1 and 2 already exists (as these were plotted as old bars 2 and 3), so these don't redraw. The new bar 3 data didn't exist before, this needs drawing from scratch. This gives the appearance of 'moving' bars around.

As a different example, watch what happens when you move the bars one unit across, but they are spaced **two** units apart. You should see all bars draw from scratch each time.

```
from ipywidgets import *
import bqplot.pyplot as plt

initialIndex = 0
idxSlider3 = IntSlider(min=0, max=20, step=1, 
    description='Index',value=initialIndex)

''' I want to update the bar chart with this function '''
def update_chart3(change):
    with bar3.hold_sync():
        bar3.x = [idxSlider3.value, 
             idxSlider3.value + 2, 
             idxSlider3.value + 4]
        bar3.y = [idxSlider3.value, idxSlider3.value, idxSlider3.value] 

idxSlider3.observe(update_chart3, 'value')  

fig3 = plt.figure(animation_duration=1000)

bar3 = plt.bar(x=[0, 1, 2], y=[1, 1, 0])

play_button3 = Play(min=1, max=20, step=1, interval=1000, initial_value=0)
jslink((play_button3, 'value'), (idxSlider3, 'value'))

VBox([HBox([idxSlider3, play_button3]), fig3])
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.